# idirafter flag inserts a new character while macro expansion in gcc 5.2.0

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, embedded-linux, preprocessor, gcc5.2

During the compilation of a C file I used `idirafter` flag to mention the directory to look if it does not find the file in any of the locations mentioned using `-I`. To simulate the problem I have written a small sample program which is as below.

I am not sure why, when `CLI_CONFIGURE_MODE` expands, there is a new line added before and after the symbol. If anyone can help me out then it will be really helpful.

**Include file:**
sample.h

```
#define CLI_CONFIGURE_MODE "/exec/configure"
```

**Test C file:**
sample.c

```
#include "sample.h"    
#define FORM(cmdstr,modestr) command cmdstr; mode modestr; should be in previous line
    FORM("dummy_command" , CLI_CONFIGURE_MODE)
```

**Snippet of preprocessor output of the file:**

```
define __DECIMAL_BID_FORMAT__ 1     
# 1 "<command-line>"     
# 1 "waste.c"     
# 1 "../waste_include/waste.h" 1 3 4     
#define CLI_CONFIGURE_MODE "/exec/configure"     
# 2 "waste.c" 2     

#define FORM(cmdstr,modestr) command cmdstr; mode modestr; should be in previous line

    command "dummy_command"; mode    
    # 5 "waste.c" 3 4     
    "/exec/configure"    
    # 5 "waste.c"     enter code hereenter code here
    ; should be in previous line
```

Command line used to compile the file:-

```
x86_64-wrs-linux-gcc -idirafter../waste_include -E -dD waste.c > 1
```

Comment: I've improved formatting (for easier reading and understanding).

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: I understand in a normal C program compilation the new line really doesnt matter. But I was using the preprocessor to expand on all the macros and use the preprocessor output to implement something at work. It worked fine with 4.6.3 compiler but when i had to port it to 5.2.0, I am facing this issue.